# physics library for iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im looking for a free strong physics library for iphone programming (Objective C).

im trying to develop a very simple game for now to know and explore my capabilities.

Comment: You may also want to checkout: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two commonly used [Chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics) and [Box2D](http://box2d.org) . You might also want to check [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org) if you're developing a 2d game. Ray Wenderlich got a [very nice set of articles](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) about developing games for iPhone, so you might want to check them out too.

Comment: Chipmunk is based on this seminal paper: http://graphics.ethz.ch/Downloads/Publications/Papers/2003/Tes03/Tes03.pdf